# Problema con fetch y CORS en React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, api, fetch

Estoy haciendo prácticas en React usando API de https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users y todo funciona bien en local server pero cuando mando a subirla en [Github](https://github.com/) con [gh-pages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gh-pages) tengo un error en consola:

> Access to fetch at 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users' from origin 'https://fc0l.github.io' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

el codigo que tengo es:

```
componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(users => this.setState({ user: users }));
}
```

Comment: Eso tiene sentido?, que no te funcione en github pero si en local?, que cosa mas extraña...

Comment: tiene sentido porque en el local es probable que no tenga los certificados https y las políticas de CORS no aplica.

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIÓN 2022/2023 y listo! Adios dolores de cabeza

app.use(cors({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" : "http://localhost:3000/" }));

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y explica cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer].

Answer (score -1):

tengo ese mismo problema en estos momentos.
revisa lo siguiente:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43262121/trying-to-use-fetch-and-pass-in-mode-no-cors

en la cabecera debes
incluir:

```
        params = {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            mode: 'no-cors',
        };
```